# Memory efficiency of max function in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, max

I have a very large matrix which is close to maxing out available memory, and my script fails due to insufficient memory to execute it. At some point, I have to compute the maximum value of said matrix, `D`. Is there a difference, memory wise, between `max(D(:))` and `max(max(D))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
max(D(:))
```

reshapes the matrix (no copy of the data is made) and computes the maximum value of the resulting vector.

```
max(max(D))
```

computes a maximum projection of the matrix, yielding a row vector, and then computes the maximum value of that vector.

Thus, the second option needs intermediate memory that the first one doesn’t.

Comment: If you reshape with [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), will it be different?

Comment: @SardarUsama: `reshape` and `squeeze` never copy data, the new array shares data with the old one (lazy copy). Other functions such as `permute` must copy data because the ordering changes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that